# How to rotate sprite with drag

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Im trying to rotate a sprite when i drag my finger across the screen. So what i want is when I drag my finger to the left, the sprite rotates to the right and vice versa, I cant figure out how to do it. Can anyone help.
I've tried using the function "touchesMoved" but I am not sure if that's where I should put the code or it should be in a new function or what.

ps. sorry i am very new to spritekit, swift and xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SKSpriteNode.zRotation` property to rotate the sprite.
And use the `touchesBegan`  and `touchesMoved` function to track the swiped distance.

```
var previousPoint : CGPoint!

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

   previousPoint = (touches.anyObject() as UITouch).locationInView(self.view)
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    let currentPoint = (touches.anyObject() as UITouch).locationInView(self.view)

    let distance = currentPoint.x - previousPoint.x

    previousPoint = currentPoint

    sprite.zRotation = sprite.zRotation + distance/100.0

}
```

Comment: This. You should track the cumulative drag (instead of frame-by-frame) to make it stable; otherwise it will jump wildly and look very bad. Also, don't forget to reset tracking state on `touchesEnded`.